# VBA that doesn't allow Auto_Open to Run

Tags: vba, excel

I have two spreadsheets. For ease of example code we will use Book1 and Book2. Book1 contains one sheet and Book2 contains two sheets.

Book2 contains the code:

```
Function Auto_Open()
sheets(1).range("B1:B50").formula="=vlookup(A1,Sheet2!A1:C50,3,False)"
End Function
```

Book one contains code like the following:

```
Function UpdateBook()
Workbooks("Desktop\Book2.xls").open
workbooks("Book2").sheets(2).values=workbooks("Book1").sheets(1).values
workbooks("Book2").close
End Function
```

I want to prevent the Auto_Open on Book2 from running when it opens as a result of the function in Book1 opening Book2. Is this possible to do using a segment of VBA code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable Events before open book2:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Workbooks("Desktop\Book2.xls").open
...
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force the Automation Security setting to Disable Macros, and then return it to it's original state like so:

```
Dim secAutomation As MsoAutomationSecurity
secAutomation = Application.AutomationSecurity
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable

Workbooks("Desktop\Book2.xls").open
workbooks("Book2").sheets(2).values=workbooks("Book1").sheets(1).values
workbooks("Book2").close

Application.AutomationSecurity = secAutomation
```

This has the added benefit of not asking the user if they want to enable macros when opening a macro embedded file.